# What's a good textbook with lots of real life examples on GLM and statistical inference?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references

I am teaching myself statistical inference, and now I am learning about generalized linear models. I am looking for lots of serious examples to work on. I want to make sure that my understanding is correct. What are good resources for that? (I want to avoid data sets where the answer is not readily available to me. Garbage in, garbage out.)

Comment: Hi: Jhhn fox's companion to applied regression has some. don't know if it's as plentiful as you need nor if there are solutions but it's worth checking out.

Comment: Hutcheson, G. D., & Sofroniou, N. (1999). *The multivariate social scientist: Introductory statistics using generalized linear models.* London: Sage. This is an excellent book on the GLM with quite a number of examples. Used it myself, so do recommend

Answer (score 6):

The CRAN package GLMsData contains nearly 100 real life datasets that are analyzed in the textbook on GLMs by Peter Dunn and myself. Our book includes complete runnable code and output for each dataset:

Dunn, PK, and Smyth, GK (2018). *Generalized linear models with examples in R*. Springer, New York, NY.

Further curated datasets without complete analyses can be found at http://www.statsci.org/data.